# SpriteKit node not respecting position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xib

I have added a `SKNode` to my `SKView` by using this code:

> `tile.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()`
>   `tile.position = CGPoint(x: 64, y: 64)`
>   `self.addChild(tile)`

However, after fiddling with window sizes in the `MainMenu.xib` file, the position of `tile` [becomes inaccurate](http://i.imgur.com/QJMXtOI.png) even when the `SKView` lines up with the window itself:

How do I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by inaccurate?

Comment: See the [picture](http://i.imgur.com/QJMXtOI.png): the shape's position from the bottom left should be uniform (64 x 64), but instead it has moved off the bottom of the window.

Comment: `tile.position` is actually the centre point of the sprite by default. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/anchorPoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the tile's anchor point might make it easier to place. I'm not 100% clear on where precisely you want to place that tile, but if you were trying to get that tile lined up on the bottom edge, and 64 from the left edge of the parent, you could simplify things by moving the anchor point of the tile to its bottom left before placing it.  By default, as rakeshbs points out, the anchor point is at the center of the tile.

```
tile.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
tile.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
tile.position = CGPoint(x: 64, y: 0)
self.addChild(tile)
```

Maybe you're already aware of the ability to modify the anchor point on a SKSpriteNode, if so please disregard; perhaps I'm not fully understanding your issue.